# Unity Android Touch.position, can't move

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hey I am new to javascript and Unity. I am making my first app and I'm trying to get touch.position to work on my android phone. I just can't figure out how to get my character(a ball named Bal) to move left,right,up and down. Also can't get Bal to jump.

Here is my code:

```
#pragma strict

var rotationSpeed = 100;
var jumpHeight = 5;
//(x,y,w,h) pixel coords.
var rectButton1 = Rect(-0.12, 0.13, 76.1, 96.61);
var rectButton2 = Rect(0.21, 0.13, 76.1, 96.61);
var rectButton3 = Rect(0.81, 0.26, 15, 58);
private var isFalling = false;

function Update () {
    for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches) {
    if (rectButton1.Contains(touch.position)) {
            var rotation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
            rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
            rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.left * rotation);
    } else if (rectButton2.Contains(touch.position)) {
            var rotation2 : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
            rotation2 *= Time.deltaTime;
            rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.right * rotation2);
    } else if (rectButton3.Contains(touch.position) && isFalling == false) {
            rigidbody.velocity.y = jumpHeight;
    }
            isFalling = true;
}
}

//No infinite jump!
function OnCollisionStay ()
{
isFalling = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what touch.position returns? Stick a Debug.LogWarning(touch.position) in there,  so you get some feedback about it.

Comment: Would I have to use the Android SDK emulator? If so I can't get that to work sadly.

Comment: no, when you run it in the Unity Editor, it shows debug messages at the bottom of the screen (Red for errors, Yellow for warnings).

Answer (score 0):

In Unity, Touch position and mouse position is taken as **BOTTOM LEFT** corner as origin, while GUI components are considered as origin at **TOP LEFT** corner. To adjust this difference, you will have to subtract the current position from Screen.height.

***Vector2 touchPos = vector2(touch.position.x, Screen.height-touch.position.y);***

i.e. In your case

```
for (var touch : Touch in Input.touches) {
Vector2 touchPos = Vector2(touch.position.x, Screen.height-touch.position.y);
if (rectButton1.Contains(touchPos)) {
        var rotation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
        rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.left * rotation);
} else if (rectButton2.Contains(touchPos)) {
        var rotation2 : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
        rotation2 *= Time.deltaTime;
        rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.right * rotation2);
} else if (rectButton3.Contains(touchPos) && isFalling == false) {
        rigidbody.velocity.y = jumpHeight;
}
}
```

Comment: I got the ball or my character to move on screen but it doesn't rotate sadly... I ended up using one of the standard assets(mobile) scripts

Comment: ok.. But always remember the origin for touches and origin for GUI is different.

Comment: I figured it out with the standard assest mobile package! Thank you guys for help though!

Answer (score 0):

The script from The Game Contriver move the object to the touch position at a constant speed regardless of the distancce between the two points.. You can modify it as per your needs..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TapToMove : MonoBehaviour {
//flag to check if the user has tapped / clicked. 
//Set to true on click. Reset to false on reaching destination
private bool flag = false;
//destination point
private Vector3 endPoint;
//alter this to change the speed of the movement of player / gameobject
public float duration = 50.0f;
//vertical position of the gameobject
private float yAxis;

void Start(){
    //save the y axis value of gameobject
    yAxis = gameObject.transform.position.y;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    //check if the screen is touched / clicked   
    if((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        //declare a variable of RaycastHit struct
        RaycastHit hit;
        //Create a Ray on the tapped / clicked position
        Ray ray;
        //for unity editor
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        //for touch device
        #elif (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_WP8)
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        #endif

        //Check if the ray hits any collider
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit))
        {
            //set a flag to indicate to move the gameobject
            flag = true;
            //save the click / tap position
            endPoint = hit.point;
            //as we do not want to change the y axis value based on touch position, reset it to original y axis value
            endPoint.y = yAxis;
            Debug.Log(endPoint);
        }

    }
    //check if the flag for movement is true and the current gameobject position is not same as the clicked / tapped position
    if(flag && !Mathf.Approximately(gameObject.transform.position.magnitude, endPoint.magnitude)){ //&& !(V3Equal(transform.position, endPoint))){
        //move the gameobject to the desired position
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, endPoint, 1/(duration*(Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, endPoint))));
    }
    //set the movement indicator flag to false if the endPoint and current gameobject position are equal
    else if(flag && Mathf.Approximately(gameObject.transform.position.magnitude, endPoint.magnitude)) {
        flag = false;
        Debug.Log("I am here");
    }

    }
    }
```

You can find the entire article at the following link
[Move To Tap / Click Position - The Game Contriver](http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/10/move-to-mouse-click-touch-position-unity.html)